# Gray box appears in right side of pdf file

Tags: pdf

When I save a Word document to a pdf file, I am getting a gray box on the right side of the page that I DON'T want and can't delete.  Help!

Comment: Sounds like the comment box from Word... Does it span the whole height of the page?

Comment: It would help a lot to be able to see a screenshot of the document.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click the *Analysis* tab (or ribbon or whatever the foolish point is called).
2. In the *Surveillance* area, click *Program Markup.* All packages are picked.
3. Uncheck *Markup Area Highlight.* Say goodbye to the grey box!!

Not in the MS Word help, as I have really had the capability to figure out. Otherwise, it's completely worded to make certain that you can only find it if you currently acknowledge that you need to uncheck *Markup Location Highlight!*

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to delete all comments in Word before saving it in PDF. In Word, go to Review and in Comments select Delete. Then click Delete all comments in Document. Save and then save as a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Images created in some programs (e.g. Powerpoint) seem to maintain some definition of the shapes that can differ in how Word interprets them, but this doesn't become apparent until you save to PDF. I'm not sure if this is simply that they're vector images.

Try the following:

Open your image in MS Paint and save it without making any changes

To do this quickly:

right-click the file in Explorer, tap e --> ctrl-s --> (y?) --> alt-f4.

Then, insert the new image into Word and save to PDF again